# Set APPLICATION_ENV in Zend framework 3

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I've enabled development mode using `composer development-enable` . How can I check in my module's `config/module.config.php` that development is enabled or not?

I've also added `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development` in public/.htaccess and tried to use it in `module.config.php` using `echo APPLICATION_ENV;exit;` but it doesn't give me environment.

How I can set and get application environment in zend framework 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [correct function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) ;)

```
$environment = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

Usage for config in ZF2/3:

```
$env = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'); // Expect null or "development"

$modules = [];

if ($env === 'development') {
    //Array of modules used only for development
    $modules = array_merge_recursive($modules, [
        'Zf2Whoops',
    ]);
}
```

In just Zend Framework nothing special happens with the usage of `composer development-enable`. However, if you use [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) at some point, it will create a `development.config.php` file for you which disables application caches.